# Custom mapping hybrid_property

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have the problems with the configuration of the mapper models with `hybrid_property`.
How to properly configure `hybrid_property`?

```
class FooTable:
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    name_translations = Column(JSONB, nullable=False)
    name = hybrid_property(...)

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name_translations):
        self.name_translations = name_translations

# columns = [name_translations]
attributes = tuple(columns) + FooTable.__table_args__
table = Table(FooTable.__tablename__, metadata, *attributes)
mapper(Foo, table, properties=**HOW???**)
```

Thanks for help.